# How to use yaml template variable as a part of value in Concourse CI

Tags: concourse

When I try to use template variable, e.g. `{{hostname}}` as a part of value, it gets wrapped with double quotes.

How to add a variable w/o quotes?

Example:

```
---
resource_types:
  - name: maven
    type: docker-image
    source:
      repository: patrickcrocker/maven-resource
      tag: latest

resources:
  - name: maven-snapshot
    type: maven
    source:
      url: http://{{hostname}}:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/

  - name: repo
    type: git
    source:
      uri: "git@bitbucket.org:foo/bar.git"
      branch: master{{hostname}}
```

And the result for the command `fly -t ci set-pipeline --pipeline test --config test.yml --var="hostname=localhost"` is as follows (look at `"localhost"`):

```
resources:
  resource maven-snapshot has been added:
    name: maven-snapshot
    type: maven
    source:
      url: http://"localhost":8081/repository/maven-snapshots/

  resource repo has been added:
    name: repo
    type: git
    source:
      branch: master"localhost"
      uri: git@bitbucket.org:foo/bar.git

resource types:
  resource type maven has been added:
    name: maven
    type: docker-image
    source:
      repository: patrickcrocker/maven-resource
      tag: latest
```

The reason I've included a 3rd-party maven resource is that git resource does not allow `{{}}` in the `uri`, leading to the error:

```
failed to unmarshal configStructure: yaml: line 17: did not find expected key
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

As of [concourse v3.2.0](https://concourse-ci.org/downloads.html#v320) `{{someValue}}` syntax is deprecated in favor of `((someValue))`. New syntax will understand you are trying to interpolate the string and place the value accordingly.

Replacing `{{hostname}}` with `((hostname))` will solve your issue:

```
resources:
  - name: maven-snapshot
    type: maven
    source:
      url: http://((hostname)):8081/repository/maven-snapshots/
```

---

Concourse does not support this. 
The Concourse yaml templating is very primitive and you can not insert variables in the middle of strings. 
You will need to set your `url` parameter as `http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/` and your branch parameter as `localmaster` or whatever it should be.

We know this is a problem and we are working on it, but for now you can not set variables in the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for this feature from concourse team, I've written this small executable to work around the issue in this GitHub repo:

https://github.com/sercant/inline-yaml

I prepare my config.yml like this:

```
ftp-username: username
ftp-password: password
ftp-uri: 192.168.1.2
ftp-dir: home/ftp/

ftp-uri-combined: ftp://{{ftp-username}}:{{ftp-password}}@{{ftp-uri}}/{{ftp-dir}}

ftp-uri-combined-html5: {{ftp-uri-combined}}html5
ftp-uri-combined-android: {{ftp-uri-combined}}android
```

And prepared a create-pipeline.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
TEMP=$(mktemp)

java -jar inline-yaml.jar $3 ${TEMP};
fly -t lite set-pipeline -p $2 -c $1 --load-vars-from ${TEMP};

rm ${TEMP};
```

Whenever I need to create a  pipeline, I ran:

```
./create-pipeline.sh build-plan.yml build-plan-name config.yml
```